# Hyphenate text only when necessary to prevent container overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyphenation

I'd like to insert hyphens into words only when the word is wider than the container.

If I use `&shy;` this happens:

```
For exam-|
ple      |
```

When really I want this:

```
For      |
example  |
```

For narrow containers I want this:

```
For |
exa-|
mple|
```

`word-wrap: break-word;` gives the desired behaviour but without hyphens.

```
For |
exam|
ple |
```

From my research it seems this is not possible with CSS currently.

Solution:

If you put a `<span>` with `display: inline-block` around the a word with a`&shy` character it will prevent it from breaking across lines until it has to

Comment: Any idea's on how you want to do it? Have you tried anything? or are you looking for an outside link to help? either way, please share any code you currently have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put a `<span>` with `display: inline-block` around the a word with a `&shy;` character it will prevent it from breaking across lines until it has to

Answer (score 0):

Look into css's "word-wrap" property (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp),

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

should do it.